# Microsoft Edge rendering looks bad

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I will confess i never bothered to look at IE or Microsoft Edge whilst in development. I thought I'd check at the end of the dev and see what my page looks like in different browsers. Well Safari, Chrome and FF all look fine. Then enter 'Microsoft Edge' The rendering for standard html looks appalling.

Microsoft:
[image: Microsoft edge]

Everything else:
[image: everything else]

does Microsoft Edge comply with CSS3? Do people actually spend time coding specifically for this browser to make it look better? I'd like to know what if I'm doing something wrong or if it's just a really finicky browser...

I understand i haven't included any code in this post however I'm not doing anything special for example. The above is simple a:

```
<select>
 ... 
</select>
```

Look how bad it looks...

Comment: Microsoft Edge renders form controls with the Windows look and feel, and every other browser renders form controls with the macOS look and feel (presumably because you tested every other browser on macOS to begin with). Conclude that the Windows look and feel is shit. This seems like a foregone conclusion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Edge uses his type of style to render web pages. Even other pages that looks fine on any other browser, but on Edge they look different because of Metro style.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the reply. How do i get rid of this Metro style and make it look normal (as defined http://www.dictionary.com/browse/normal?s=t  ) like every other web browser where it actually looks good?

Comment: Actually you can't, i'm sorry, i don't like it neither. In fact i'm using google chrome

Comment: @MarMan29: There is no other way than to convince your users to switch to Mac, if your definition of "normal" and "good" is "uses the macOS look and feel".

Comment: I'm brand agnostic i don't really can't if it's Microsoft, Solaris or Mac I'm just annoyed that Edge rendering is different and require me to make changes to CSS specifically to cater for it.

Comment: @MarMan29: Of *course* Edge rendering is going to be different when you compare it to every other browser *running on a Mac*, given that Edge is exclusive to Windows. If you claim to be brand agnostic, the least you can do is to be fair to Edge by running the other browsers on the same platform Edge runs on in your tests. Otherwise your question just comes off as finding something to be mad at Microsoft about, especially with that kind of attitude. And we've had *plenty* of that in the last 20 years.

Comment: @MarMan29: Chrome does still adopt its own unique look and feel on Windows, but Firefox is much more faithful to the OS, looking very similar if not identical to Edge.

Comment: Damn i just tested Chrome and was going to reply back. I guess i'll have to spin up FF too now and report back it won't be tonight though. I still think it will look better. I actually like Microsoft and have fond memories of dos games and doom2 on windows 95. I guess some elements just looks different in different os' and some people have preferences. I'll probably go back now and remove all the <select> and make then custom div drop downs to make things look consistent.

Comment: @MarMan29: Yeah, you're going to want a custom look and feel if you need consistency across platforms.